# Springboot 2 RESTful application deployed to heroku using Procfile

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, procfile

I've tried numerous configurations to deploy my Restful Springboot 2 app to heroku using a procfile to no avail. I've tried several of the suggestions/solutions here.

**Procfile:** 
`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=stage -cp target/classes:target/libs/* com.rabbittab.RestFulApp`

**Heroku logs:**
`2020-04-24T14:57:59.344561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"`.

Greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I think instead of target/libs/* you should provide target/dependency/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `-Dserver.port=$PORT` to the Procfile.
I think the problem is that your app does not bind to the port provided by Heroku.